# sitemap submission error

Tags: url, sitemap

I am facing the issue of a sitemap error in the google search console. I have submitted the sitemap manually in the search console and submission was successful but further, it is not discovering URLs in the child category like the post, category, and pages.

I submitted the sitemap in Bing Webmaster and it was successful in every aspect. Please could anyone help me in finding, what's the problem?